# Difficulty creating proper RavenDB query

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to implement the logic below in a RavenDB query, but receive

`System.NotSupportedException: Could not understand expression`

related to the `scores.Any` expression.  I understand why that is, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a working option.

```
public IRavenQueryable<Person> Apply(IRavenQueryable<Person> query)
{
    var scores = new List<string>();
    if (_a) scores.Add("A");
    if (_b) scores.Add("B");
    if (_c) scores.Add("C");
    if (_u)
    {
        scores.Add("");
        scores.Add(" ");
        scores.Add("\t");
        scores.Add(null);
    }

    return from p in query
           where scores.Any(score => score == p.Score)
           select p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that the ravendb linq provider isn't operating on your list so scores.Any() makes zero sense to it -- it compiles but as you can see it dies at runtime.

The trick is to reverse field a bit and ask if p.Score is in an array of the scores if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If we modified your example to use IDocumentQuery, it should work with:

```
public IDocumentQuery<Person> Apply(IDocumentQuery<Person> query)
{
    var scores = new List<string>();
    if (_a) scores.Add("A");
    if (_b) scores.Add("B");
    if (_c) scores.Add("C");
    if (_u)
    {
        scores.Add("");
        scores.Add(" ");
        scores.Add("\t");
        scores.Add(null);
    }

    return query.AndAlso().WhereIn(x => x.Score, scores);
}
```

Your initial document query could look something like:

```
var myQuery = RavenSession.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Person>();
```